# A few reference questions about the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, power-series

I'm looking at the article [Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) and I have a few questions.

Under the "[Special cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula&oldid=1111593014#Special_cases)" section, there is a notation $\DeclareMathOperator{\ad}{ad}$

$$ \log(e^X e^Y) = X + \frac{\ad_X}{1 - e^{-\ad_X}}Y + O(Y^2),$$

but it doesn't provide a reference for this formula. Who discovered this representation of the BCH formula and does it hold in the general case for general $X$ and $Y$ or is this only valid in the case $[X,Y] = sY$?

Another question related to this, is there a name for when $[X,Y] = sY$?

A third question is, what is the proper formal Taylor expansion for the $\frac{\ad_X}{1-e^{-\ad_X}}$ term? Is this convergence of this formal Taylor expansion limited by any particular spectral radius? The wiki article does not seem to go into detail about that.

Comment: There is a nice discussion of this, not answering your questions perhaps, on https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/baker-campbell-hausdorff-formula/

Comment: @BenMcKay, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431252/a-few-reference-questions-about-the-baker-campbell-hausdorff-formula#comment1109963_431252), there are three articles in [that tag](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/baker-campbell-hausdorff-formula); did you mean [Tao - The $C^{1, 1}$ Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/the-c11-baker-campbell-hausdorff-formula)?

Comment: I don't know any name for it, but the situation $[X, Y] = s Y$ is precisely the case when there is a representation of the Lie algebra of the so called “$a x + b$ group” $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$ sending $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ to $X$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ to $Y$ … so perhaps that could be used to make up a name?

Comment: See also the 2020 paper "Notes on the theorem of Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff-Dynkin" by Michael Mueger (https://www.math.ru.nl/~mueger/PDF/BCHD.pdf).

Comment: And w.r.t. numerical integration of diff eqs, see the discussion surrounding eqns. 2.45 and 3.2 on pp. 33 and 38 of "Lie-group methods" by Iserles, Munthe-Kaas, Nørsett, and Zanna (http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/na/NA_papers/NA2000_03.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

$\DeclareMathOperator\ad{ad}$The identity
$$\log(e^X e^Y) = X + \frac{\ad_X}{1 - e^{-\ad_X}}Y + O(Y^2)\tag{$*$}\label{star}$$
is due to Poincaré [1], who showed that $W(t)=\log (e^X e^{tY})$ solves the ODE
$$W'(t)=\frac{\ad_{W(t)}}{1-e^{-\ad_{W(t)}}}Y,\;\;W(0)=X.$$
The identity \eqref{star} is the solution to first order in $t$. It holds generally, you don't need $[X,Y]=sY$.

[1] H. Poincaré, [*Sur les groupes continus*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ve8RPdkg3t0C&pg=PA220&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false), Trans. Cambridge Phil. Soc., **18**, 220–255 (1900). [JFM 31.0386.01](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:31.0386.01)

Comment: There's an article [Ton-That and Tran - Poincaré's proof of the so-called Birkhoff–Witt theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9908139) that may be apposite (though I have no idea of its historical accuracy).